# C++ streams question (explanation of comment in code)

Tags: c++, stream, iostream

I am playing around with the fastCGI application found [here](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/examples/echo-cpp.cpp).

The following comment is in the code:

```
    if (content) delete []content;

    // If the output streambufs had non-zero bufsizes and
    // were constructed outside of the accept loop (i.e.
    // their destructor won't be called here), they would
    // have to be flushed here.
```

My knowledge of C++ streams is rather weak. Could someone please explain the following:

1. which streambufs are being referred to in the comment?
2. under what conditions would the streambufs had non-zero bufsizes?

last but not the least, can someone point to a resource (pun intended) online that provides a clear but gentle introduction to C++ IO streams?

Comment: Reference for streambuf: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which streambufs are being referred to in the comment?

It's referring to `request.out`, which is part of the reassigned `cout`:

```
FCGX_Request request;
...
    fcgi_streambuf cout_fcgi_streambuf(request.out);
    ...
    cout = &cout_fcgi_streambuf;
```

This reassignment means that the user can call

```
cout << "Content-type: text/html\r\n"
     << ...
```

and have the text show-up on either the console (for testing) or across the network when run as a CGI application. Thus, one code sample can run in multiple environments.

---

> under what conditions would the streambufs had non-zero bufsizes?

The comment you're referring to is a friendly reminder. The `fcgi_streambuf` objects in this sample code are constructed in a loop; when the loop ends, they go out of scope and are thus destructed.

The comment warns that in many circumstances, the user would have to flush the output stream:

```
cout.flush ();
```

Comment: Is that a VC5 version of `cout`?  In standard C++, you'd redirect cout by calling `std::cout.rdbuf(&newstreambuf);`

Comment: @Ben I excluded a lot of the sample code from the linked file, but there's a conditional compilation with `HAVE_IOSTREAM_WITHASSIGN_STREAMBUF` that uses the construct you're talking about.